# optimize model using metrics ROC in caret

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

In hyperparameter search to optimize my binary classification model with caret package, I use ROC as metric. I assume what happens in the search is: for everything combination of hyperparameters, AUROC is calculated using the predicted probability of the positive class. Then the parameters with the highest AUROC is selected as bestTune.

My question is: Shouldn't we need to specify the positive class when using ROC as metric? From all the online sources, it does not seem to be necessary.  I'm a little confused with this. Can anyone kindly clarify me on this question? Thanks a lot.

```
xgb.fit <- train(
    Target~.,
    data=df,
    method = 'xgbTree',
    metric = 'ROC',
    trControl = xgb.control,
    tuneGrid = xgb.tuneGrid)
```

Comment: Could you clarify if by "specify the positive class" do you mean to specify which of the two classes is "positive" (if so, I believe this is on-topic as the answer depends on conceptual knowledge)

Comment: I figured out and am answering my own question.  Specifying which one is positive class does not affect the calculation of AUROC. It matters when we calculate sensitivity, specificity, etc.  Here we are optimizing with AUROC, so it does not matter.